# Trifold Symmetry giving odd results

Tags: modeling

i'm making a spitfire and my previous propellor was incredibly off regarding symmetry so i'm redoing it.

I've looked up how to do trifold symmetry and found the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44055/how-to-make-trilateral-3-fold-symmetry) however these are my results: [image: odd result]this is how i set it up [image: Setup]

does anyone know what i might be doing wrong? perhaps how to fix this? or an even better method of doing this?

Comment: Notice an empty is used as object offset in answer in link posted rather than the cube in yours.  Is it a Mk XIVe Spit?

Comment: hahaha, no my name is derived from the Spiteful prototype, this is a Mk Ia. but i have just switched to an empty object and it still doesn't work @batFINGER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's an issue with offsets and / or scale.

Here is the default cone, with its origin moved to the tip.  (Add default cone, move cursor to (0, 0, 1) then transform > Origin to 3d cursor. Now we add an empty at this point and make it the object offset.

ie the origin of one blade (basically its pivot point) and the array modifier object offset, the empty, are at the same point.  Ok that's offset dealt with.

For your blade, make the origin the pivot point in centre of propeller nose cone. Even if this means it is outside the blade mesh.

Rotate the empty to 120degs on y, and "whallah" a cone propeller.

Make sure the scale of the empty and prop (in my case the cone) is (1, 1, 1) by applying scale, or this will effect the array modifier result. (increasing or decreasing in size of each iter)

[image]

Lastly, if I make the empty the parent of the cone, I can move the whole set up by moving the empty without upsetting the array mod.

Comment: thanks, it was indeed the scale, instead of rescaling the blades and later scaling them back i rescaled the empty to the blades.